# meaning of capital S in long ls output

Tags: ls

What does this long listing mean?

```
$> ls -l developer.haml
```

-rw-rwSr-- 1 humon apache ......

I know what a usual listing means and I know all about what it means to be read 'r', write 'w', and executable 'x'.  But what is 'S'?

Comment: Apart from the answers below, see `man 2 chmod` which reveals also the `sticky bit`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`S` means setuid bit enabled, while `s` means setuid bit and executable bit both enabled.

Comment: A good article that covers all the flags: http://danielmiessler.com/study/unixlinux_permissions/

Comment: Except this appears in the group bits, so it's setgid.

Answer (score 6):

From my `man 1 ls`:

> Each field has three character positions:
>
> ...
>
> ```
>   3.   The first of the following that applies:
>
>        S     If in the owner permissions, the file is not exe-
>              cutable and set-user-ID mode is set.  If in the
>              group permissions, the file is not executable and
>              set-group-ID mode is set.
>
>        s     If in the owner permissions, the file is exe-
>              cutable and set-user-ID mode is set.  If in the
>              group permissions, the file is executable and set-
>              group-ID mode is set.
>
>        x     The file is executable or the directory is search-
>              able.
>
>        -     The file is neither readable, writable, exe-
>              cutable, nor set-user-ID nor set-group-ID mode,
>              nor sticky.  (See below.)
> ```

Basically,

```
S == setuid/setgid && not executable
s == setuid/setgid && executable
x == not setuid/setgid && executable
- == not setuid/setgid && not executable
```